# llncs: Upright text in theorems and lemmas

Tags: amsthm, lncs

By default the `llncs` class defines a host of theorem-like environments, without my loading `amsthm`. Some of them, such as Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, set their text in italics.

I think this is not very good, typographically, and I would like to change it. Besides manually writing `\normalfont` after each `\begin{theorem}`, what can I do?

In a similar vein, I would also like to put a `\qed` before the end of each `\end{proof}`. Maybe there is a similar solution?

Comment: If you don’t like those presets, define your own theorem environments?

Comment: If your class is based on `amsthm`, you should be able to redefine `\qedsymbol` and use it in `proof` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface (personal opinion): `llncs.cls` is not particularly pretty, so I would only use it if I had to (because of submitting to a Springer venue). In this case, I would not change the predefined settings, because this is the way the elements (like theorems) are supposed to look like. It's up to the editor to define a common appearance.

Regarding your questions: You can define your own environments, like

```
\spnewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{}
```

If you want/have to reuse the `theorem` environment, you can redefine it:

```
\let\theorem\relax
\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{}
```

To obtain a square at the end of proofs, `llncs.cls` defines  the command `\qed`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\let\theorem\relax
\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  The theorem I worked on all my life.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  The result is obvious.\qed
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick! Yes, I'm submitting to a springer venue, or I definitely wouldn't use the llncs class :p